# zsh `history n` displays the first n entries instead of the last n entries

Tags: zsh

I read the doc for `history` and it says:

```
  history [n]
  history -c
  history -d offset
  history -anrw [filename]
  history -p arg [arg ...]
  history -s arg [arg ...]
          With no options, display the command history list with line
          numbers.  Lines listed with a *  have  been  modified.   An
          argument  of  n  lists only the last n lines.
```

But in my zsh, it always displays the first n lines. I need to use `history | tail -n` to show the last few lines.

1. Is there any option set wrongly? How to correct it?
2. Moreover, how to print history without line number and time stamp so that I can convert a portion of the history to a script

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The documentation for zsh `history`, in zshbuiltins(1), is:

> #### history
>
> Same as `fc -l`.

where `fc -l` is:

> #### fc -l [ -LI ] [ -nrdfEiD ] [ -t timefmt ] [ -m match ] [ old=new ... ] [ first [ last ] ]
>
> If `first` is not specified, it will be set to -1 (the most recent event), or to -16 if the `-l` flag is given.  If `last` is not specified, it will be set to `first`, or to -1 if the `-l` flag is given.  However, if the current event has added entries to the history with `print -s` or `fc  -R`, then the default `last` for `-l` includes all new history entries since the current event began.
>
> When the `-l` flag is given, the resulting events are listed on standard output.

so run:

```
history -<n>
```

with a hyphen-minus, as in `history -16`, to see the last n lines of history in zsh.

Comment: I get why I was wrong. I typed `man history` in my `zsh` and hoping it will give me the doc for `zsh history`. But it actually leads me to the doc for `bash`. I actually also tried `help history` and hoping it is for the builtins; but that did not work. Would you please also tell me how to access the doc for these zsh builtins? Thanks very much

Comment: I found that in my `zsh`, `history` is an alias to `fc -il 1`, is there a way to locate the definition so that I can change it?

Comment: @LiuSha: Oh, zshbuiltins(1) means `man zshbuiltins` (it’s the manual page named “zshbuiltins” in section 1). As for the alias… are you using oh-my-zsh? I’m not sure where it is (looking), but you can use `fc -l` directly instead of `history` as a workaround, or overwrite the alias by adding `alias history='fc -l'` to the end of your .zshrc.

Comment: Yes. I am using oh-my-zsh. I just now grepped the alias and located it in `lib/history.zsh`. Thank you.